# Blowup of double point in $\mathbb{A}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In his notes about Du Val singularities Miles Reid considered an example of blowup of quadric cone $X=\{xz-y^2=0\}\subset\mathbb{A}^3$ in the origin $P=(0,0,0)$. The statement on the page 8 says that for the blowup $\sigma:X_1\to X$, $K_{X_1}=\sigma^*K_X$.

The proof literally says the following.

If  $\sigma:B\to\mathbb{A}^3$ is the blowup of $P$ with the exceptional surface $F=\sigma^{-1}(P)\cong\mathbb{P}^2\subset B$, then $K_B=\sigma^*K_{\mathbb{A}^3}+2F$. The blowup $X_1$ is contained in $B$, and $X_1=\sigma^*X-2F$ (because $X$ has multiplicity $2$). Thus by adjunction

$$K_{X_1}=(K_B+X_1)|_{X_1}=(\sigma^*K_{\mathbb{A}^3}+2F+\sigma^*X-2F)|_{X_1}=\sigma^*(K_{\mathbb{A}^3}+X)|_{X_1}=\sigma^*(K_X).$$

Here are points I missed:

1) Why actually we have the equality $X_1=\sigma^*X-2F$? What does he mean by "because $X$ has multiplicity $2$"?

2) Why the adjunction formula is true for singular varieties?

And here is the link for his notes
http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/surf/more/DuVal.pdf

Comment: I guess he meant that $F$ has multiplicity 2 in the inverse image of $X$ in $B$. For the second question, note that $X_1$ and $B$ are smooth, so the adjunction formula is valid.

Comment: No, it means there the multiplicity of $X$ as a singularity.

Comment: $X$ has a double point, but $X$ is not really of multiplicity 2. Compute the blow-up to see where the $2F$ comes from.